# iFrame in a Safari Extension "Popover"

Tags: html, safari, google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

I have a Chrome and Firefox extension, and I am making the same one for Safari.

These plugins all have a popup. In other words, an icon you click on and a page opens up. My Chrome extension popup opens an HTML page in te plugin folder with an iFrame. The FF extension links directly to the PHP page on the server for the popup.

I need to do with Safari what I have done with Chrome. I need to make a local HTML page which has an iFrame to the page on the server. This works in chrome, but the iFrame in Safari is just blank.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: I think Apple blocks popovers from loading anything not local to the extension, perhaps in a misguided attempt to make extensions more secure. At any rate, I haven't had any more luck than you at attempting to load web pages in a popover.

Comment: Post 7seven years ago...So can I use iframe in the new safari app extension popover now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple doesn't allow iFrames to be loaded within the popover... but!
You can do XMLhttpRequest to any domain (say what now?). Yes XMLhttpRequest to ANY domain.
Example:

I use this for my selectors (because I didn't want to load jQuery or Mootools in extension):

```
function $(element) {
    return document.getElementById(element);
}
```

And just do a XMLhttpRequest like so:

```
http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('get', 'http://yoursitehere.com/extension/');
http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    $('target-div-id').innerHTML = http.responseText;
}
```

In this way you can fill the target div with the HTML.

Comment: Thanks!!! I was thinking something like this. I have CORS (Cross Origin Requests) on my server anyway. But I did not know Safari allows to make requests to any domain. :O

Comment: One more thing... How can I send data back to the page without using an iFrame?

Comment: You can only request data. So if you want to add content to the popover you should do a GET/POST request and put the response somewhere in the content of the popover. But if you want to send data to your domain/page you should just do something with the request and return no response..